# Change file-specific indentation rules in WebStorm / PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

I have a project that used to be indented with 2 spaces, and now it's indented with four spaces.

The problem is, back when it was indented with two spaces, PyCharm would present little dialogues saying "would you like to indent this file with 2 spaces?". I said yes to a few of those dialogues, and now that I've changed the whole project to indent with 4 spaces, those few files are still stuck on 2 spaces (and PyCharm's ESLint complains when I use four spaces in those files).

How do I get rid of those file-specific indentation rule overrides?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such file-specific settings nowhere in the Settings/Preferences. The dialogs that you have seen are *probably* caused by `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` option (hint: use search in Settings). try disabling that option and force file reformat.

Answer (score 3):

Idea will detect the indentation used and keep using it for those two files. That is set in `Editor / Code Style`:

[image]

I've turned mine off, but this could cause files to have different indentations. e.g. in python you can pass `-tt` in the cli which will cause the interpreter to raise an error because of the different indentation used in the file.

However, in `Editor / Code Style / Inspections` you can set it to warn you about the different indentation when you open the file:

[image]

If detected just run `Code / Reformat Code` from the menu.